# Using flexbox for navigation menu using pseudo :before is splitting it in two lines

Tags: css, flexbox, pseudo-element

Using media-query and flexbox with 2 break points was working fine, before I've added the :before content to split it with "|":

```
.navigation li+li:before {
    content: '/ ';
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jk37gbpn/2/)

How can I  make it stay  in-line with the rest of the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on each `li`

```css
.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F05A24;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}
.navigation li+li:before {
  content: '/ ';
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to use `space-around` layout on smaller screens and get `/` to be in middle of `li` you can do something like this instead

```css
.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}
li {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F05A24;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}
.navigation li:before {
  content: '/ ';
}
.navigation li:first-child:before {
  content: '/ ';
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Close! But it looks odd because the / is too close to the next word. Is  there any way to put it right in between?

Comment: It looks funny ( http://i.imgur.com/RPSqsud.png ) when the width is just before the breakpoint but I guess is just a limitation of the :before. Thanks!

Comment: That's actually really nice and work in all latest browsers. Thanks @Nenad!

Answer (score 0):

**You set you links as `block` elements**, so the behavior has nothing wrong.
remove the block propertie from links and reset it to `inline-block` to allow `vertical` `padding`.

`display` unset: https://jsfiddle.net/jk37gbpn/3/

`display:inline-block;` https://jsfiddle.net/jk37gbpn/4/

```css
 ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   font-weight: 300;
   font-size: 18px;
 }
 .navigation a {
   display:inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #F05A24;
   padding: 14px 16px;
 }
 .navigation a:hover {
   font-weight: 400;
   color: black;
 }

 .navigation li+li:before {
   content: '/ ';
 }
 @media all and (max-width: 820px) {
   .navigation {
     justify-content: space-around;
   }
   .navigation a {
     font-size: 120%;
   }
   #logo {
     display: none;
   }
 }
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Different approach, but same issue as above: It looks odd because the / is too close to the next word. Is  there any way to put it right in between?

Comment: @CristianoMaia well give :before BFC so padding or margin can be used here , the trouble came from the fact that <a> was a block and broke the line , **the point of my answer was to explain the behavior** The op seems to play with flex but doesn't know yet what display behavior (or float or position) involves yet ;)

Comment: It looks funny ( i.imgur.com/RPSqsud.png ) when the width is just before the breakpoint but I guess is just a limitation of the :before. Thanks! I'll try either having the | as a element by itself (with fixed width) so it's properly spaced, OR go back to the old inline-mode (no flexbox), text aligned to the center and font-size vw.